# Why SELECT SQL executed each time even configured SecondLevel and Query Cache in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache, second-level-cache, query-cache

hi I Configured second level cache/query cache in my spring mvc - hibernate application.

Configuration Part:

```
#EH Cache
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
```

HibernateProperties:

```
private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    properties.put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", environment.getProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"));
    properties.put("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class",
            environment.getProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class"));
    properties.put("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache","hibernate.cache.use_query_cache");
    // properties.put("", environment.getProperty(""));
    return properties;
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY,region="myLpn")
public class MyLpn {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="myLpnSeq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="myLpnSeq",sequenceName="MYLPN_SEQ")
    private Long lpnId;
    private String tcLpnId;
//I have all setter/gettters properly
```

Service Impl:

```
@Transactional
public MyLpn getLpnById(Long lpnId) {
    MyLpn lpn = null;
    try {
        lpn = lpnDaoImpl.getLpnById(lpnId);
    } catch (DataAccessException dataAccessException) {
        System.out.println();
        throw new DataAccessResourceFailureException("Exception Occured");
    }
    return lpn;
}
```

DAOImple:

```
public MyLpn getLpnById(Long lpnId) {
    Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Query query = currentSession.createQuery("FROM MyLpn myLpn WHERE lpnId = :lpnId");
    query.setLockMode("myLpn", LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
    query.setParameter("lpnId", lpnId);// "lpnId"
    query.setCacheable(true);
    List<?> returnedList = query.list();
    return (MyLpn) returnedList.get(0);
}
```

But my doubt is 
When i request an Entity I see SQL query in the app logs. This is fine, lets suppose that For the first time Entity has been fetched from DB and Stored in Second->First Level Cache.

But When I request for the same entity second time again I see the SQL in the app logs. This is making me confuse.

Can you please let me know why Hibernate is executing a SQL even i configured both second level and query cache.

Comment: `throw new DataAccessResourceFailureException("Exception Occured");` you really should chain the original exception so you don't lose information.

Comment: Are you requesting the same `lpnId` the second time?

Comment: Yes Jim. I am requesting same lpnId